# jQuery progress bar giving values to certain divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simulated multi page layout I am working on. Some of them have conditional statements to hide or show them. Right now I have it set in the function to increment the progress bar by 5 every time the user clicks next. The problem is that if I have a few of the divs hidden and they never appear, the progress bar does not increment correctly. Is there a way to give each div a value so that it reads it when it is marked unhidden so that the progress bar is updated accordingly? [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/65yQ8/)

This is my Div layout:

```
<div class="Page" id="DealerInfo" style="display: block;">
    <script>$( "#DealerInfo" ).load( "formPages/DealerInfo.php" );</script>
</div>

<div class="Page hidden" id="AdditionalLocations" style="display: none;">
    <script>$( "#AdditionalLocations" ).load( "formPages/AdditionalLocations.php" ); </script>
</div>

<div class="Page" id="OwnerInfo" style="display: none;">
    <script>$( "#OwnerInfo" ).load( "formPages/OwnerInfo.php" );</script>
</div>

<div class="Page" id="SalesInfo" style="display: none;">
    <script>$( "#SalesInfo" ).load( "formPages/SalesInfo.php" );</script>
</div>
```

This is the function

```
function nextForm() {
        $(".Page:visible").hide( ).nextAll( ".Page" ).not(".hidden").first().show();
        var value = $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value" );
        $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "option", "value", value + 5 );
        $('.progress-label').text(value + "%");

}
```

These are my buttons:

```
<p class="navigation"><button class="button" type="button" onclick="prevForm();">Previous</button>                                                                              
                              <button class="button" type="button" onclick="nextForm();">Next</button></p>
```

Comment: can you offer jsfiddle demo

Comment: You can give the div a class of "complete" and then count the number of divs complete vs not complete and calculate a % complete.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/65yQ8/

Comment: I have 20 divs right now possibly adding more later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply calculate a percent done as a function of how many `.not('hidden')` divs are before your active one divided by the total number of `.not('hidden')` divs?

```
function updateProgress() {
    var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
    if($(".Page:visible").length < 1) {
        value = 100;
    } else {
        value = Math.floor(100*($(".Page:visible").prevAll(".Page:not(.hidden)").length)/($(".Page:not(.hidden)").length));
    }
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", value);
    $('.progress-label').text(value + "%");
}

function nextForm() {
    $(".Page:visible").hide().nextAll(".Page").not(".hidden").first().show();
    updateProgress();
}

function prevForm() {
    $(".Page:visible").hide().prevAll(".Page").not(".hidden").first().show();
    updateProgress();
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/26tqA/)

This will scale automatically as you add sections.  You won't need to add any values to the divs at all.

If you are going to show/hide `.hidden` divs depending on answers to questions, simply leave `:not(.hidden)` out of the selectors:

```
function updateProgress() {
    var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
    if($(".Page:visible").length < 1) {
        value = 100;
    } else {
        value = Math.floor(100*($(".Page:visible").prevAll(".Page").length)/$(".Page").length);
    }
    $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value", value);
    $('.progress-label').text(value + "%");
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/26tqA/1/)